# Bokeh - How to Change Glyph Attribute in JS Callback?

Tags: javascript, data-visualization, bokeh

I'm making a plot in Bokeh 0.13.0, and I want to change the `x` attribute of a `Ray` glyph in a custom JS callback.

I need to know 2 things:

1. How do I pass the Glyph into the callback?
2. How do I reference the `x` attribute once it's been passed?

Here's the gist:

```
vline = Ray( x=vline_x, y=0, length=0, angle=1.5708, line_width=1)
plot.add_glyph(source, vline)

callback = CustomJS(args=dict(source=source), code="""
    var data = source.data;

    // CHANGE ATTRIBUTE HERE

    source.change.emit();
""")
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. I passed the `GlyphRenderer` object for the Ray as an item in the `CustomJS` args dict. I was then able to access the `Glyph` object for the Ray and was able to change its attributes from there.

Might also have worked if I'd just passed the `Glyph` object in the first place, but oh well.

Updated code:

```
vline = plot.add_glyph(
    source,
    Ray(x=vline_x,y=0, length=0, angle=1.5708, line_width=1)
)

callback = CustomJS(args=dict(vline=vline, source=source), code="""

    vline.glyph.x = <new_value>;

    source.change.emit();
""")
```